# Select button by looping through all innerHTML

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to get all the buttons using queryselector and select the particular button by looping through and finding innerHTML.

After finding the particular button, when click event is passed, nothing happens.

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.spirit.com/"
Do Until IE.readyState = 4: Application.Cursor = xlDefault: DoEvents: Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
IE.document.querySelector("label[for='radio-oneWay']").Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
IE.document.querySelector("input[id='flight-OriginStationCode']").Click
Set elems = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")

For Each elem In elems
    If (elem.innerHTML) = " Aguadilla, Puerto Rico (BQN) " Then
        elem.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next elem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two airport boxes can be assigned by simulating input using `SendKeys` then the click event will be triggered. The date-input and other textbox will be set separately. Here is the code which implements this function:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.spirit.com/"
Do Until IE.readyState = 4: Application.Cursor = xlDefault: DoEvents: Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
IE.document.querySelector("label[for='radio-oneWay']").Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

Set elems = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")

Set txt1 = IE.document.getElementsByName("originStationCode")(0)
txt1.Focus
SendKeys ("BQN")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

Set txt2 = IE.document.querySelector("input[id='flight-DestinationStationCode']")
txt2.Focus
SendKeys ("BDL")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
IE.document.querySelector("input[id='flight-Date']").Value = "2020/10/09-2020/10/19"
IE.document.querySelector("input[id='promoCode']").Value = "xx"
      
IE.document.querySelector("button[type='submit']").Click
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I tried that but the date field doesn't appear until you select the airports via click event. I can set the input value for both origin airport and destination airport. but that doesnt bring the date field which appears only when the click event is triggered.

Comment: @Svj I've updated my answer, please check it. It can trigger the event in airport input box with `SendKeys`.

Comment: appreciate your help. Yes, the sendkeys method worked. Sendkeys("BQN") doesn't work perfectly all the time so I changed it to Sendkeys("BQN", TRUE) and the waited for 1 second.